# show that the function $z = 2x^2 + y^2 +2xy -2x +2y +2$ is greater than $-3$

Tags: quadratic-forms

Show that the function

$$z = 2x^2 + y^2 +2xy -2x +2y +2$$

is greater than $-3$

I tried to factorize but couldn't get more than $(x-1)^2 + (x+y)^2 +(y-1)^2 - (y)^2$.

Is there any another way to factorize or another method??

Comment: What's the power of $x$?

Comment: It is 2 .i have edited it now

Comment: $(y-1)^2=y^2+1-2y$, you have got $+2y$ over there. So, the factorization will rather have $(y+1)^2$ .

Comment: $z(2,-3)=-3$ and $z(2+a,-3+b)=-3+a^2+(a+b)^2 \,$.

Comment: $\neg z>3 \forall (x,y)\in \Bbb R^2$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HINT:

$$z = 2x^2 + y^2 +2xy -2x +2y +2=(x+y+1)^2+(x-2)^2+2-4-1$$

**Derivation** :

Let $$ 2x^2 + y^2 +2xy -2x +2y +2=(x+y+a)^2+(x+b)^2+2-a^2-b^2$$

$$\implies  2x^2 + y^2 +2xy -2x +2y +2=2x^2+y^2+2xy+2x(a+b)+2ay+2-a^2-b^2$$

Comparing the coefficients of $y, a=1$

Comparing the coefficients of $x, a+b=-1\implies b=-1-a=-2$

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to look for a factorisation, you can always use some analysis:

Let $q(x,y)=2x^2+y^2+2xy-2x+2y+2$. Then
$$\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}(x,y)=4x+2y-2,\ \frac{\partial q}{\partial y}(x,y)=2y+2x+2.$$ Therefore the unique critical point of $q$ is $(2,-3)$ which has image $q(2,-3)=-3$. Now it only remains to see that this point is a minimum. Indeed, the corresponding Hessian matrix is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 2\\
2 & 2\\
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which is positive defined.

Comment: Can one be sure it is an absolute minimum ?

Comment: herefore the unique critical point of q is (2,−3) which has image q(2,−3)=−3. Now it only remains to see that this point is a minimum. Indeed, the corresponding Hessian matrix is ...can u explain this??

Comment: @Tony: If (2,-3) were not an absolute minimum then there would be local maxima, which cannot exist because there are no other critical points.

Comment: @rattanjot: What I did here is just a generalisation of what one does in one variable. I computed the derivative and I found that it is zero at (2,-3). To determine whether this point is a minimum, a maximum or a saddle -or a more complicated critical point- I computed the second derivatives, that is the Hessian matrix.

Answer (score 5):

The equation $2x^2 + y^2 +2xy -2x +2y +2=0$ is a conic in the plane; so you can use the good old methods to put it in canonical form; set $x=X+a$ and $y=Y+b$, to get
$$
2X^2+4aX+2a^2+
Y^2+2bY+b^2+
2XY+2bX+2aY+2ab
-2X-2a+
2Y+2b+
2
=2X^2+2XY+Y^2+(4a+2b-2)X+(2b+2a+2)Y+2a^2+2ab+b^2-2a+2b+2
$$
and you get zero coefficients for $X$ and $Y$ by solving
$$
\begin{cases}
2a+b=1\\
a+b=-1
\end{cases}
$$
that is $a=2$ and $b=-3$. Now the polynomial becomes
$$
2X^2+2XY+Y^2-3
$$
and now it is clear that its values are $\ge-3$, because $2X^2+2XY+Y^2$ is positive definite (the conic is an ellipse), having negative discriminant $4-8=-4$. Or you can write it as
$$
X^2+(X+Y)^2-3
$$

Comment: I like the this geometric method. Both in your answer and mine the key is to solve the same linear system.

Comment: @A.Bellmunt Yes, finding the center of the ellipse.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way of doing it that requires no previous knowledge of 3D analytic geometry or calculus:

You are trying to show $z = 2x^2+y^2+2xy-2x+2y+2 \gt -3$, or, (more usefully) that $z+3 = 2x^2+y^2+2xy-2x+2y+5 \gt 0$

$$z+3 = 2x^2+y^2+2xy-2x+2y+5 \\= 2x^2+(2y-2)x+(y^2+2y+5)$$

Now we can use the quadratic formula on it as if it were just a 2<sup>nd</sup> degree polynomial in $x$.

$$x = \frac{2-2y\pm \sqrt{4(y-1)^2 - 8(y^2-2y+5)}}{2} = 1-y\pm(y+3)i$$

This is clearly only a real value when $y=-3$, so a point of intersection will only occur if $y=-3$.  Another interpretation is that the vertex of the elliptic paraboloid is at $y=-3$.

We now substitute $y=-3$ into our original equation to find the parabola that represents the minimum value of the function WRT $y$:

$$z+3 = 2x^2+y^2+2xy-2x+2y+5 = 2x^2 - 8x + 8$$

We find that this has a double-root at $x=2$ (can be obtained by using quadratic formula again, although its much simpler this time).

So, we have determined that the vertex of this elliptic paraboloid is at $(x,y) = (2, -3)$.  We can now evaluate the function at this point: $z+3 = 2x^2+y^2+2xy-2x+2y+5 = 0$, or $z=-3$. Clearly, the original proposition, $z>-3$, is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

$$z=2x^2 + y^2 +2xy -2x +2y +2$$

$$\implies 2x^2+2x(y-1)+y^2+2y+2-z=0$$

As $x$ is real, the discriminant of the above Quadratic equation must be $\ge0$

$$\implies \{2(y-1)\}^2-4\cdot 2\cdot(y^2+2y+2-z)\ge0 $$

$$\implies (y-1)^2-  2\cdot(y^2+2y+2-z)\ge0 $$

$$\implies 2z\ge y^2+6y+3$$

$$\text{Now, }y^2+6y+3=(y+3)^2-6\ge -6$$

Comment: @rattanjot, observe that the equality occurs when $y+3=0\iff y=-3,$ and $x=-\frac{2(y-1)}{2\cdot 2}=\frac{1-y}2=2$ which is the same conclusion like my first answer